# Private method called error

Tags: ruby

Have written a method; when I try to run it, I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: private method ‘subtotal’ called for 39.99:Float
at top level    in grades.rb at line 9
Program exited with code #1 after 0.04 seconds.
```

Following is the code:

```
def subtotal(qty = 1)
  return nil if self.to_f <= 0 || qty.to_f <= 0
  self.to_f * qty.to_f
end

book = 39.99
car = 16789

puts book.subtotal(3)
puts car.subtotal
puts car.subtotal(7)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you declare a method outside of any class, it's a private method, which means it can't be called on other objects. You should open the class that you want the method to go into and then put the method definition in there. (If you want it in multiple classes, either open a common superclass or put it in a module and include that module in all the classes.)

Comment: Question: If I don't define a class, shouldn't it default to the Object class? That was my understanding of what Ruby would do. Is that understanding incorrect?

Comment: @pdenlinger: That is correct, but it defines it as a *private method* of Object. It's not merely a default scope — it's a special behavior designed to mimic defining a function in a language like Python.

Comment: @Chuck Why the above code runs flawlessly in Ruby 2.3?

Comment: @Lokesh: I don't have Ruby 2.3 on this computer to test specifically, but IIRC this works differently in irb vs. ruby, so if you're trying it in irb, that would explain it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to include the method `subtotal` into any class? E.g.

```
class Numeric
  def subtotal(qty = 1)
    return nil if self.to_f <= 0 || qty.to_f <= 0
    self.to_f * qty.to_f
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this and seeing that you seem to be calling the `subtotal` method on a variable containing of the `Float` class.  This is equivalently `Float.subtotal` .  Now, the problem is easy to see then.  You haven't defined the subtotal method as part of the Float class.